# Apache Rampart not working with JBoss 6

Tags: web-services, jboss, apache-axis, rampart

I'm using Axis 2 1.5.4 to deploy web services on JBoss 6.0.0 and using Apache Rampart 1.5.2 to implement UserName Token security for the web services. My services gets deployed successfully and I can see the web services policy in the WSDL.

But when I launch the web service through SOAP UI , it doesn't ask for any security information and directly calls my web service method and does not even invoke the `PasswordCallBackHandler` class. The same service and security works with Tomcat but not with JBoss.

Sample from my WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
- <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">  
- <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken">  
- <wsp:ExactlyOne>  
- <wsp:All>  
- <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">  
- <wsp:Policy>  
  <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />   
  </wsp:Policy>  
  </sp:SupportingTokens>  
  </wsp:All>  
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>  
  </wsp:Policy>
```

Below is my services.xml:

```
 <service>  
    <module ref="rampart" />
        <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">SimpleService</parameter>  
        <operation name="echo">  
            <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>  
        </operation>      

    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu=  
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"

        xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">  
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>  
        <wsp:All>  
          <sp:SupportingTokens  
              xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">  
            <wsp:Policy>  
              <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>

            </wsp:Policy>  
          </sp:SupportingTokens>  

           <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">  
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>MyHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>  
           </ramp:RampartConfig>  
        </wsp:All>  
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>  
    </wsp:Policy>  
    </service>
```

Am I missing some configurations from JBoss? Please help me in resolving the issue as I am totally stuck.